# Post-receive script results in untracked/modified files

Tags: git, version-control

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

Using Git, I'm attempting to develop a setup so that I can deploy changes to my production server using a bare repository placed on the production server.

My set up is as follows:

- Local Repository with remote `production` that points to a bare repository on the production server. (e.g. `git@productionserver.com:/opt/git/caf.git`)
- Created bare repository on the production machine as `git` user via `git --bare init` in the above directory.

I created a post-receive hook script that (complete copy of the script is in the link below, but omitting because I believe this is the relevant portion.):

`GIT_WORK_TREE="$DEPLOYDIR" git checkout -f`, where `$DEPLOYDIR` points to the production copy of the repo.

Once everything was set up, I ran `git push production +master:refs/heads/master` from my local copy to bring the bare repository up to date.

**What's working**

When committing changes locally and pushing my changes to the aforementioned bare repository, files are updated/deleted/modified in the production copy as I expected.

**The Problem**

If I go to the production copy and run `git status`, the HEAD is not up to date, thereby resulting in a bunch of uncommitted untracked changes or modifications from the push. (Essentially all changes that I pushed are showing up as modifications)

I can resolve this by running `git reset --hard origin master`, but this doesn't seem correct.

**My Question**

*How can I set this up so that the production repo is also up to date without having to update it by force?*

For reference, I'm following this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/one-click-app-deployment-server-side-git-hooks/

Comment: So, is this a correct claim/rephrase, and if so, does it make the problem clearer?  Claim: your production server has a git repository it doesn't use (`$DEPLOYDIR/.git`), a bare repository that it does use (`/opt/git/caf.git`), and a work-tree that it does use (`$DEPLOYDIR`)?

Comment: @torek - I feel like an idiot.  So with this setup the `$DEPLOYDIR` _shouldn't_ have a git repository - is that correct? To date, I'd been logging into the server and fetch/merging; obviously this is an attempt to replace that.

Comment: Yes, this kind of auto-deploy setup means the place you `checkout` to is just a directory, with no underlying repository.  Which, added on top of a bare repository, equals: a regular repo with regular work dir, but split-up to accomodate git's pickiness. :-)