# Post-receive hook causing untracked files in production folder

Tags: git, githooks, git-bare

I checked the google for similar questions and the only thing that I found with similar problem is in this topic:
[Post-receive script results in untracked/modified files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506600/post-receive-script-results-in-untracked-modified-files)

The situation is this. I guide from the [4.4 Git on the Server - Setting Up the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/fa/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) tutorial.

Making bare repo on computer 1:

```
$ cd /srv/git
$ mkdir project.git
$ cd project.git
$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /srv/git/project.git/
```

Pushing the 1st version to bare repo on computer 2:

```
# on John's computer
$ cd myproject
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Initial commit'
$ git remote add origin git@gitserver:/srv/git/project.git
$ git push origin master
```

Cloning in production folder on computer 1

```
git clone git@gitserver:/srv/git/project.git
$ cd project
$ vim README
$ git commit -am 'Fix for README file'
$ git push origin master
```

All looking good push/pull from both machines.

Now making the post-receive hook in hook folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production..."
        git --work-tree=/var/www/html/project --git-dir=/srv/git/project.git checkout -f
    else
        echo "Ref $ref successfully received.  Doing nothing: only the master branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

OK. Pushing from computer 2 when I commit 2 files "test_file1" and "test_file2"  to bare. Success.
Browsing to see if the hook worked in production folder on computer 1. Ok the files "test_file1" and "test_file2" are there.

```
get status
```

In production folder echoing this:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        public/test_file1
        public/test_file2

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I have .git folders in both production folder and local(testing) folder.
Any idea if this is normal? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally would not have a `.git` folder in `production` folder: only your `post-receive` hook in the bare repo is allowed to modify (`checkout -f`) said `production` folder.

A `production` folder should not know anything about Git (unless Git is an essential element to actually run the program/project stored in "production")

Comment: Ok I understand the comments in the first topic now thanks to your explanation here. So I deleted the `.git`  folder after I cloned the project in production folder. One more thing. If user upload files(web site) in production and I want to test(see) it in my local(testing) folder?

Comment: @HristianYordanov Then you would need a listener on your server which would detect the changes, and add them in a separate cloned repository, in a separate branch, and push to your local testing server (if reachable) or notify you through email (for you to pull from that separate repo/branch. Note that if there is to be two-way changes, they have to be in their own separate branch, in order to avoid any collision: you can merge those branches later on locally, and push back to your bare repo in order to publish the result of the merge in the production folder.